# Yii Framework file input skipOnEmpty validation always fails

Tags: php, yii

I  am currently doing a project in PHP Yii framework.
I have a form with file input field called company_logo.For the field I have added the following rule in the model  `[['company_logo'],'file','skipOnEmpty'=>false]`
When I upload file, it shows

> Please upload a file.

even if I uploaded a file.

When I remove the

> skipOnEmpty
>   it is uploading the file.I have researched several places for the issue.But couldn't find a solution.

The controller, view and model are given below

> View - add_company.php

```html
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

    /*Assigning the parameters to be accessible by layouts*/
    
  foreach($layout_params as $layout_param => $value) {
      
   $this->params[$layout_param] = $value;
  
   }
   ?>
    
    <div class="form-group">
         
    </div>

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Add Company</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
 

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>


                  <div class="box-body">
                  <?php if(isset($message)&&sizeof($message)): ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="callout callout-info  alert-dismissible">
                     <h4><?php if(isset($message['title']))echo $message['title'];?></h4>
                     <p>
                         <?php if(isset($message['body']))echo $message['body'];?>
                     </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <div class="form-group"> 
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'company_name')->textInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'company_address')->textArea(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                      
                     </textarea> 
                     <div class="form-group"> 
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'company_logo')->fileInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>
 

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'admin_name')->textInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                     
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'admin_email')->textInput(array('class'=>'form-control','type'=>'email')); ?>
                     </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'admin_phone_number')->textInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                                         </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    
                      <?= $form->field($model, 'admin_password')->passwordInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <?= $form->field($model, 'retype_admin_password')->passwordInput(array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>
                    </div>
                    

                  <div class="box-footer">
                    
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                  </div>
                  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>                
              </div>
</div>
```

> Controller - CompanyController.php

```html
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter; 
use app\models\CompanyModel;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

global $username;
class CompanyController extends Controller
{ 
     
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    } 
    
     public function actionEntry()
    {
    }
    
    public function actionAdd() {
              
     
      $layout_params=array(
       'username'=>'admin',
       'sidebar_menu1_class' =>'active',
       'sidebar_menu12_class' =>'active',
       'dash_title' => 'Companies',
       'dash_sub_title'=>'Add new company'
       
      );
        $message = array();
        $model = new CompanyModel();
        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
          echo "hello";
          $model->company_logo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'company_logo');
          echo "world";
            if ($model->company_logo && $model->validate()) {                
                $model->company_logo->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->company_logo->baseName . '.' . $model->company_logo->extension);
            } else {
          echo "Yo Yio ture";   
          exit;
            }

             $model->add_company();
             $message['title'] = 'Wow !';
             $message['body'] = 'Successfully added company '.$model->company_name;
         }else {
                                        $message = $model->getErrors(); 
                                     //   print_r( $message );
                                     //   exit;
         }          
     return $this->render('add-company', ['model' => $model,
             'layout_params'=>$layout_params,
             'message' =>$message
        ]);
        //return $this->render('add-company',$data);
    }
    public function actionSave() {
     //print_r($_POST);
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {         
     $data = array(
      'layout_params'=>array(
      'username'=>'admin',
      'sidebar_menu11_class' =>'active'
     )
     );//
    
  
         
    }
     public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }
 }
```

Model - CompanyModel.php

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii;
use yii\db;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class CompanyModel extends Model
{
    public $company_name;
    public $company_address;
    public  $company_logo;
    public $admin_email;
    public $admin_name;
    public $admin_password;
    public $retype_admin_password;
    public $admin_phone_number; 
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            
            [['company_name'], 'required'],
            [['company_address'],'required'], 
            [['admin_name'],'required'],
            [['admin_email'],'required'],
            [['admin_password'],'required'],
            [['retype_admin_password'],'required'],
            [['admin_phone_number'],'required'],
            [['company_logo'],'file','skipOnEmpty'=>false]
        ];
    }
    public function add_company() {
      Yii::$app->db->close();
      Yii::$app->db->open();
      $comm =  Yii::$app->db->createCommand("CALL create_company('".$this->company_name."','".$this->company_address."','".$this->admin_email."','".$this->admin_phone_number."',1)");
      return $comm->execute() ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237661/skip-on-empty-not-working-in-yii2-file-upload ?

Comment: That didn't actually help :(

Comment: So you removed that filter, added a code to check the file's size in order to manually check if a file has been uploaded and it still doesn't work? Can you update the code in your question accordingly and share the results?

Answer (score -2):

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii;
use yii\db;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class CompanyModel extends Model
{
    public $company_name;
    public $company_address;
    public  $company_logo;
    public $admin_email;
    public $admin_name;
    public $admin_password;
    public $retype_admin_password;
    public $admin_phone_number; 
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            
            [['company_name'], 'required'],
            [['company_address'],'required'], 
            [['admin_name'],'required'],
            [['admin_email'],'required'],
            [['admin_password'],'required'],
            [['retype_admin_password'],'required'],
            [['admin_phone_number'],'required'],
            [['company_logo'],'file','skipOnEmpty'=>false],//here the comma is missing
        ];
    }
    public function add_company() {
      Yii::$app->db->close();
      Yii::$app->db->open();
      $comm =  Yii::$app->db->createCommand("CALL create_company('".$this->company_name."','".$this->company_address."','".$this->admin_email."','".$this->admin_phone_number."',1)");
      return $comm->execute() ;
    }

}
```