# How to update uploaded file in yii2

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have used following to upload file and save it in folder and database. And also i can download that file. Now I want to write a controller to update the uploaded file. I don't know how. I'm new in yii2 framework. Help me guys.

This is my controller create.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
$model = new Documents();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{      
        $project =$model->doc_name;
        $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
        $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->save();

        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->reference_no]);
        } 

        else {

        return $this ->render('create', [
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
        }         

}
```

Update.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->reference_no]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: upload the file in same way as done in actionCreate then save your model. You can delete old file to save space.

Comment: I already did it. But i got errors. I don't know what to do. I'm new in yii2 framework.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Nothing happen.

Comment: see the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237661/skip-on-empty-not-working-in-yii2-file-upload

Comment: I did it. I got no errors. But nothing happen. Even the other textField is not updating.